# Sum of the geometric series $ \frac{1}{(2^{k})^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^2}+1 $

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, summation

Did I get the sum of this geometric sequence right? (Last few terms fix is geometric now)

$$ \frac{1}{(2^{k})^2}+\frac{1}{(2^{(k-1)})^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(2^2)^2}+\frac{1}{(2)^2}+1 $$

Using

> $S_n = \frac{a_1(r^n-1)}{r-1}$ with $a_1 =1,r=\frac{1}{2^2}, n=k \Rightarrow S_n = \frac{4-4^{1-k}}{3}$

Comment: The answer below by Ròcherz addresses a few issues that your question has. For that reason, I want to ask: did you mean $$\frac1{(2^k)^2}+\frac1{(2^{k-1})^2}+\cdots+\frac1{2^2}+1$$instead? That would make your series geometric, and at the same time explain why $\frac1{2^2}$ is the penultimate term.

Comment: @Arthur, yep that is the sequence, seems i got to fix up some terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sum such as $$\frac1{2^{k^2}} +\frac1{2^{(k-1)^2}} +\frac1{2^{(k-2)^2}} +\frac1{2^{(k-3)^2}} +\ldots +\frac1{2^2} +1$$ for positive $k$ isn't a geometric series because the exponents don't follow an arithmetic progression. Also, how come the second-to-last term is $1/2^2?$

Comment: Omm alright, the original sum was this $(\frac{n}{2^k})^2+(\frac{n}{2^{k-1}})^2+...+(\frac{n}{2})^2 +n^2  $.

Comment: Oh, alright. That original sum of yours is indeed a geometric sum. Your formula for $S_n$ is off by one index, though: $$S_n = \frac{a_1(r^{n\bbox[yellow]{+1}}-1)}{r-1}.$$

Comment: So I should of had the number of terms in my series be (k+1) instead of k, then the sum would be $\frac{4^{k+1}-1}{3*4^k}$